# "Add Project Data Source" from an OData Service does not work

Tags: wcf, data-binding, entity-framework-5, odata, wcf-data-services

I have created a WCF Data Service (v5.6.0) based on a (model-first) Entity Framework (v5.0) model. I created a new/fresh model to be sure to have all 'defaults' in place (also tried disabling lazy loading but didn't help).

**Working**

I can now create a Service Reference in a test application (Windows application). From code I can use the generated proxy as if it is the actual model. I can query the data. So far so good.

**Wish**

However what I would like is to bind my WCF service to a data bound control, e.g. a DataGridView. For this we would like to use the Visual Studio designer so that we can select columns and so on.

**Bug?**

What I do for this is I click the arrow of the control and then use the "Choose Data Source" dropdown to select "Add Project Data Source" and then select "Service" to create a new service reference. This works without errors. However no data source is created and when I select the arrow again and go to "Choose Data Source" I see absolutely no data source. Also no errors. It gracefully fails.

Am I missing something obvious or is this a bug? Any help will be appreciated.

tnx!